# Scout Helicopter maps in Obliteration mode

Tags: battlefield-4

I want to play Obliteration game mode with a scout helicopter.

In which maps can I play?

Comment: Note: With the recent patch I'm not sure that this question is relevant any more. I think helicopters have been removed from Obliteration, at least on PS4.

Comment: As one DICE employee confirmed, all obliteration servers were mistakenly set as 'infantry mode'. It is expected to be fixed soon.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of that, thanks for letting me know! Obliteration was a lot less fun with just quads and RHIBs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play with a scout helicopter in these maps in Obliteration:

- Zavod 311
- Hainan Resort
- Flood Zone
- Paracel Storm

**Tip #1**: I would definitely recommend to start in Zavod 311 because after this map comes Hainan Resort and Flood Zone so you can play with a scout helicopter for three consecutive rounds.

**Tip #2**: Out of these four maps, only Zavod 311 has a mobile anti-air vehicle - your biggest nightmare - so be extra careful.

**Tip #3**: The map with most cover for a helicopter is Flood Zone. Then comes Zavod 311/Hainan Resort and lastly Paracel Storm, which have almost no cover. My advice on that is make sure you have an unselfish engineer in your helicopter to repair you and harass the enemy helicopter with anti-air rockets (Stinger and Igla).